# Firefox - container does not adapt width to content when image is scaled down

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a weird issue on Firefox, it kind of sounds like this one: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=829958 but it has been fixed few years ago.

I have an big image inside a wrapper having `width: auto; height: 100%;`. The only constraint applied to the image is `height: 100%;`.

The image is correctly scaled down on all browsers to the maximum height available. On almost all browsers, the wrapper is also scaled down to the new (and effective) size of the image. This is not the behavior on Firefox (tested on 50+), Firefox does scale down the image but not the wrapper who keep the original width of the image as its own width.

Here is a codepen to better simulate the issue: https://codepen.io/Tronix117/pen/MEogMv

The `img-wrapper` can not be in `display: inline;` because of effects applied on it. More intermediate `div` can be added if needed.

On the codepen, don't mind the fix width of `scroll-wrapper` it's a dynamic value, as well as all transforms values.

Images can be of various width and height and the CSS should be responsive.

The idea is to produce a coverflow with different images using Swiper lib.

I have been struggling on this all day, so thank you for your help!

---

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#viewport {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  perspective: 1200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#scroll-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 3000px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate3d(-500px, 0, 0);
}

.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

#img-wrapper-1 {
  border-color: blue;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(30deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

#img-wrapper-3 {
  border-color: green;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-30deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="viewport">
      <div id="scroll-wrapper">
        <div id="img-wrapper-1" class="img-wrapper">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1200" />
        </div>
        <div id="img-wrapper-2" class="img-wrapper">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1200" />
        </div>
        <div id="img-wrapper-3" class="img-wrapper">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1200" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting problem!

It's most likely a bug with Firefox, though I think that it's probably caused by Firefox unable to find the correct reference `height` value for all the cascaded `height: x%;` of nested elements.

So I gave `#viewport` an explicit `height` value: `height: calc(100vh - 40px);` instead of an implicit one from `top: 20px; bottom: 20px;`. And it does work!

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGRYqx

Comment: Thank you, this answer solve this specific issue, so that is great. However when applied to a more complex layout, it can not work if we don't know the "40px" value. Let's imagine some text before and after a div constraining it to scale down, now let's put the `viewport` div I use above inside this div with an unknown height. Now we have a case of dynamic height, and it can not be solve this way with `100vh - 40px`. Any other idea ?

Comment: Your example doesn't sound valid to me. Texts before and after divs don't scale it down, they wrap to the next line or flow outside the container. That's the nature of a HTML document, where "prefered width" is 100% viewport and "prefered height" is undefined. They accept and encourage vertical scrolling. Unless it's a flexbox your're talking about, in that case I don't think Firefox will have a problem, since flexbox does give the inner elements information about their height.

Comment: It was a flexbox layout I was talking about (i’m on mobile right now so difficult to give exemple). I figured out a solution by removing the flex layout and giving text bellow and above a fixed weight width. If you’re interested, I will be back with another exemple as soon as I have time.